# How does a multimeter convert voltage/current to a numerical value?

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, multimeter

Just wondering... How does a digital multimeter work ? How can it convert a voltage, a current or a resistance to a numerical value ? I guess there is some programmable chip inside, but how does this chip give a specific value to a voltage ?

For example, my arduino is capable of giving a value between 0 and 1023 to a voltage applied to one of its analog inputs. How is this implemented ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter

Comment: Looking up *multimeter* at Wikipedia would lead to *[voltmeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltmeter)* which links to *Analogue to Digital Converters (ADC)*.

Comment: There's a dedicated chip for that, which uses an ADC as others mentioned already. I once used the [7106](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn30/fn3082.pdf) in a volt meter, for example.

Comment: Do you know what a DAC is? This needs to be reasonably understood first to grasp how a lot of ADCs work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a analog signal to a digital number is, oddly enough, done by something called a *analog to digital converter*, or often A/D for short.

There are many ways this conversion can be accomplished, like successive approximation, sigma-delta, tracking, flash, and probably a few more basic strategies.  There are lots of variations and tradeoffs within the basic types too.  Most microcontrollers have successive approximation A/Ds built in.